# select between date range within speicific time period

Tags: datetime, oracle10g

I have two seperate columns for date and time each being saved in varchar2

I'm trying to query a specific range of time:

i.e. 1/1/2017 - 1/31/2017
between 6PM-6AM each day

So far I did this:

**select * from (select a.*,TO_DATE(billdate||' '||billtime,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:Mi:SS') 
as Timex from billtable a where billdate >= '2017/01/01' and billdate <= '2017/01/31')
where timex>=to_date(''2017/01/01 18:00:00','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:Mi:SS') 
and timex<=to_date('2017/01/31 06:00:00','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:Mi:SS')
order by billdate**

What can I do further or Is It the wrong way Iam going?

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be storing dates as string. Instead, you should defined billtime as date/datetime/timestamp type. The type may be DB specific, but that's the correct way to do it. If you need/want a string for you application, then your app should do the conversion.

Comment: Are you just interested in BillTable records whose BillDates fall between the beginning and end of the month AND whose BillTimes fall between 6AM and 6PM, or do you want to include rows where the BIllTime falls outside that range on days other than the first and last of the date range?  For example should 2017-01-20 04:00:00 be included or excluded from the result set? (BTW I can't upvote John Manko enough here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're stuck with the data model you have (storing dates and/or times as strings, or separately, is not a good idea) and that you are not interested in the six hours before and after the date range, the formats you've used at least allow you to query those ranges fairly simply:

```
select a.*, to_date(billdate||' '||billtime,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:Mi:SS') as timex
from billtable a
where billdate >= '2017/01/01'
and billdate <= '2017/01/31'
and (billtime <= '06:00:00' or billtime >= '18:00:00')
order by billdate, billtime;
```

With some sample data provided in a CTE:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

with billtable (billdate, billtime) as (
  select '2017/01/01', '00:00:00' from dual
  union all select '2017/01/01', '06:00:00' from dual
  union all select '2017/01/01', '06:00:01' from dual
  union all select '2017/01/31', '17:59:59' from dual
  union all select '2017/01/31', '18:00:00' from dual
  union all select '2017/01/31', '23:59:59' from dual
)
select a.*, to_date(billdate||' '||billtime,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:Mi:SS') as timex
from billtable a
where billdate >= '2017/01/01'
and billdate <= '2017/01/31'
and (billtime <= '06:00:00' or billtime >= '18:00:00')
order by billdate, billtime;

BILLDATE   BILLTIME TIMEX              
---------- -------- -------------------
2017/01/01 00:00:00 2017-01-01 00:00:00
2017/01/01 06:00:00 2017-01-01 06:00:00
2017/01/31 18:00:00 2017-01-31 18:00:00
2017/01/31 23:59:59 2017-01-31 23:59:59
```

If you already had a date, or were converting to a date - or in fact a timestamp to make this work - you could do:

```
select billdate, billtime, cast(timex as date)
from (
  select a.*, to_timestamp(billdate||' '||billtime,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:Mi:SS') as timex
  from billtable a
  where billdate >= '2017/01/01' and billdate <= '2017/01/31'
)
where extract(hour from timex) < 6
or (extract(hour from timex) = 6 and extract(minute from timex) = 0 and extract(second from timex) = 0)
or extract(hour from timex) >= 18
order by timex;
```

Comment: The last query works just fine for question I asked ,since I didn't specify earlier, Iam trying to avoid data that falls between 12am-6am on 01/01 ,

Comment: You mean adding a filter for `timex > to_date('2017/01/01 06:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD H24:MI:SS')` ?